# Parsing json using Python in Azure function app - cannot remove elements

Tags: python, json, azure-functions

I am trying to remove elements from a json doc. Here's the input json.

```
{
  "start": {
        "docId": "3723",
        "data": {
            "dId": null,
            "innerprops": {
                "pId": "4573",
                "stat": {
                    "statId": "7578",
                    "portaldata": [
                        {
                            "portalid": "67383",
                            "pairs": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1111",
                                    "loc": "denver"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "2222",
                                    "loc": "houston"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1111",
                                    "loc": "austin"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "3333",
                                    "value": "miami"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "popq"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return json after removing the pairs from the 'pairs' property where the id is not equal to "1111". E.g. return value

```
{
  "start": {
        "docId": "3723",
        "data": {
            "dId": null,
            "innerprops": {
                "pId": "4573",
                "stat": {
                    "statId": "7578",
                    "portaldata": [
                        {
                            "portalid": "67383",
                            "pairs": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1111",
                                    "loc": "denver"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1111",
                                    "loc": "austin"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "popq"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "url": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        data = req.get_json()
        for entry in data["start"]["data"]["innerprops"]["stat"]["portaldata"]:
          for pair in entry["pairs"]:
            if pair["id"] != '1111':
                del pair  
    except Exception as e:
       logging.error(str(e))
       return func.HttpResponse(str(e), status_code = 500)
    return func.HttpResponse(str(data), status_code=200)
```

However the value is only deleted locally and the full document is being returned. What am I missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with list comprehension,

```
for entry in data["start"]["data"]["innerprops"]["stat"]["portaldata"]:
    entry["pairs"] = [pair for pair in entry["pairs"] if pair["id"] == '1111']
```

Result:

```
{'start': {'data': {'dId': None,
                    'innerprops': {'pId': '4573',
                                   'stat': {'portaldata': [{'name': 'popq',
                                                            'pairs': [{'id': '1111',
                                                                       'loc': 'denver'},
                                                                      {'id': '1111',
                                                                       'loc': 'austin'}],
                                                            'portalid': '67383'}],
                                            'statId': '7578'},
                                   'url': ''}},
           'docId': '3723'}}
```